# TLS cipher order in Spring Boot 2.0.0

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to improve my SSL-Labs rating by specifying the server-preferred order of cipher suites.

How do I do this in Spring Boot 2.0.0 ?

Comment: Did you try `server.ssl.ciphers` from the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). I'm assuming they haven't moved those properties in 2.0.0

Comment: Yes, I have a list of ciphers, but SSL labs still says that the server has no preffered order. I need some way to make sure my ordering is respected.

Comment: I am using tomcat as the embedded server. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set HTTPS SSL Cipher Suite Preference in Spring boot embedded tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940608/how-to-set-https-ssl-cipher-suite-preference-in-spring-boot-embedded-tomcat)

Comment: @Catchwa, Agreed. The duplicate answer actually answers my question.