# How to enable only strong Ciphers in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Since we are using spring boot with an embedded tomcat server, so there is no Apache.

How to enable strong Ciphersonly and disallow all the weak Ciphers.

```
For Apache, modify the SSLCipherSuite directive in the httpd.conf.
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
```

But how to do this in spring boot?

Answer (score 2):

In Spring you usually use the property `server.ssl.ciphers` for this, e.g.

```
server.ssl.ciphers=HIGH,MEDIUM,!MD5,!RC4
```

For embedded Tomcat you might need to do some customization as shown in [How to set HTTPS SSL Cipher Suite Preference in Spring boot embedded tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940608/how-to-set-https-ssl-cipher-suite-preference-in-spring-boot-embedded-tomcat)