# How to set HTTPS SSL Cipher Suite Preference in Spring boot 3 embedded tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat10

Im upgrading my springboot 2.7.x application to 3.x.
I'm trying to set HTTPS SSL cipher suite preference according to server preference.
Previously my config looked like this:

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements
    WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory factory) {
    if (factory instanceof TomcatServletWebServerFactory) {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory  containerFactory = (TomcatServletWebServerFactory)factory;
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setPort(httpPort);
        containerFactory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
        containerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers((connectorCustomizer) -> {
            ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) 
  connectorCustomizer.getProtocolHandler()).setUseServerCipherSuitesOrder(true);
        });
    }
   }
}
```

i have this property in my application.properties

```
server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA
```

it worked fine in my older version of springboot.

With springboot 3.x i get the error

```
Cannot resolve method 'setUseServerCipherSuitesOrder' in 'AbstractHttp11Protocol'
```

Is there any other way to set this?

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot 3 and Tomcat 10 this could be a solution:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.coyote.ProtocolHandler;
import org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CipherOrderConfig {

  @Bean
  public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> servletContainerCustomizer() {
    return factory ->
      factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
        ProtocolHandler protocolHandler = connector.getProtocolHandler();
        if (protocolHandler instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol<?> httpHandler) {
          Arrays
            .stream(httpHandler.findSslHostConfigs())
            .forEach(sslHostConfig -> sslHostConfig.setHonorCipherOrder(true));
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Credits to @Michiel:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76959544/7794994