# SpringBoot: how to enforce specific TLS version and cipher?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

I'm setting up a spring-boot SOAP webservice which - according to the specs - should be secured by TLS. The specification  defines which version of TLS and which cipher suites should be used. In order to meet the specifications, i configured the application.yaml like this:

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    ciphers: [
      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 ]
    protocol: TLS
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2
    bundle: "web-server"
    client-auth: none
  port: 443
```

I could test using curl that the service is reachable by the client and that their communication is secured. However the TLS version and the cipher suite used do not match the server settings.

```
 SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

So it looks like client and server negotiate the most secure configuration and the settings in the application.yaml are totally ignored.

Is there a way to force the server to use a specific TLS version /cipher suite?

Comment: Show your SSL `DEBUG` logs, it will show, which configuraions are offered. You didn't mention, if your app is running standalone or deployed in a servlet container like Tomcat. If you deploy you app in Tomcat your configuration is overridden.

Comment: Which version of Spring-boot do you use? They amp up the requirement from version to version occasionally.

Comment: @ValerijDobler: i use the version 3.2.1

Comment: @dur: I'm in the context of a spring-boot app with an embedded tomcat. I looked in the log and also used wireshark, but didn't find any clue

Comment: I found another SO discussion on the same topic and it helped my successfully  enforce specific ciphers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940608/how-to-set-https-ssl-cipher-suite-preference-in-spring-boot-embedded-tomcat